# Cannot understand backbone.js tutorial example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am learning backbone.js following [this tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/), but I run into problem understanding the first example:

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods

       this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
    },
    ...
  });
  ...
 })(jQuery);
```

Q1: Why use `(function($){})(jQuery)`; instead of a perfectly fine working `(function(){})();`?

Q2: What does `_.bindAll(this, 'render')` do? How does it fixes loss of context for 'this' within method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1: by passing jquery in as a parameter you allow yourself 2 things:

1. if the need of using 2 versions of jquery arises - you are prepared
2. module pattern is probably better thought of as something well encapsulated and with well defined dependencies, so by declaring that jquery is a parameter - you declare clear dependency. Granted there are other ways of doing it (like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)), but this is also a way

Q2: `bindAll` is a utility method from Underscore.js that binds `this` for a specific method - thus, when that method is invoked (as a callback for instance) the correct `this` would be used inside of it.

For example:

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    initialize: function(){
        // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'makestuff'); 

        this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
    },
    ...
    makestuff : function() { 
        ... 
        this.stuff = ... // some action on the list's instance
    }
  });
  ...
 })(jQuery);
```

and in some part of your code you doing something like:

```
var list = new ListView({...});
$('#button').on('click', list.makestuff);
```

`this` in `makestuff` method is a reference to the above `list` and not whatever context the `on` function is in when `makestuff` is actually invoked inside it.

The actual implementation relies on using `apply` and `call` functions to bind the context of function's execution to a specific object.

Answer (score 2):

`(function($){})(jQuery)` passes `jQuery` to the self executing which is using it as `$`. This makes sure you can safely use the `$` symbol inside the closure without having to worry about interference with other libraries or even other versions of jQuery. A common example for this practice would also be passing in `window` and `document` and then using shorthands inside the closure:

```
(function(w, d, $){
$(w).resize(function({}); //equals $(window) now
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

underscore's `_.bindAll` does the following:

> Binds a number of methods on the object, specified by methodNames, to
>   be run in the context of that object whenever they are invoked. Very
>   handy for binding functions that are going to be used as event
>   handlers, which would otherwise be invoked with a fairly useless this.
>   If no methodNames are provided, all of the object's function
>   properties will be bound to it.

See **[the annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-58)** for the how.

Comment: thanks, the other answer explained in more details, sorry I chosed him